# How to solve "Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar"?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have some problems to execute command "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=25d0a6a8a078272ad5c53e5c76fb15e6a4242736".
JDK 1.8
Sonarqube 7.4
Maven 3.5.4
How could I solve my troubles?
Below I post my screen code from git bash

````
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 599 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 18123ms, dir size=7 MB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 4815ms, zip size=3 MB
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:49 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-19T11:28:56+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project traccar: Failed to upload report - An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException```
````

Comment: There are at least two things: First: `on project traccar: Failed to upload report - An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator` and second you are using a very old Sonar scanner version....

Comment: I have to use a specific version of Sonar

Comment: add -e to see the full stack trace.. (try also mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=admin )

Comment: This will simply not work cause SonarQube 7.4 needs newer versions than 3.0.2..as far as I know...

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-scanner-version-compatibility-check/11732) Sonarsource community discussion. The general policy is that there is only support for LTS versions. In your case you should plan to upgrade to [version 7.9.2](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) and update all your plugins and (in this case) the scanner. You didn't explain why you state "have to use a specific version of Sonar". If you do not want the newest features, advise your Client only to use LTS versions.